# Custom URL for jQuery

Tags: jquery, firefox, url

I am trying to create custom URLs for jQuery actions. I am not sure if this can be done or if I am using the correct terminology. I have a website that has several buttons on it and when one is click the rest slide down to show the information associated with the button. I want to make permalinks for the buttons so that visitors can share a URL that opens that particular information on load. Please forgive me if this has been answered, I didn't really know what to search for or where to start.

Here is a link to the page I have been working on to help with understanding what I would like to do.

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2600525/Overflow/home.html

In addition I am having an issue with Firefox not performing the slideToggle correctly. If anyone has any info on how to fix that I would greatly appriciated it.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

you can use `window.location.search` to update the querystring part of your url, allowing users to share specific urls that will be different according to the selected button.

```
$('#myButton').click(function(){  
  window.location.search = "location=" + $(this).val(); // or any property from your clicked button
});
```

then, when you page is visited by one of these urls, you can put a simple check for the same property, and navigate according to the provided value

```
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2600525/Overflow/home.html?location=home   ==> home page
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2600525/Overflow/home.html?location=anout ==> about page
```

using the same technique, you can utilize the `window.location.hash` for the same purpose, but now you gonna make all your buttons' `href` are like the following:

```
<a href="#WhoWeAre"></a>
<a href="#WhatWeDo"></a>
```

then use the same way to update the url, and check for the value when your page is being visited.

also I highly recommend you to visit the following page https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location which will explain the various options you have when you are dealing with `window.location`.

Comment: I am sorry but I do not fully understand what my jQuery would look like with this in place and what my href should look like. I am very new to coding and apologize for not understanding.

Comment: Mohammed provided a sample in regards to `location.search` and I provided samples in regards to `location.hash`. What else are you after? I have edited my response to contain a complete working example using `location.hash`. I hope this is what you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I worked on a site that used a lot of AJAX (load content without refreshing entire page). They wanted history and bookmarking to be possible. So we used url hashes to represent page sections with dynamic data (for example, `site.com/account#settings` or `site.com/account#profile`). Upon `(document).load` we would load the appropriate data segments based on the hash.

You can:

1. get the current hash with:

   ```
   var hash = window.location.hash;
   ```
2. set it with

   ```
   window.location = '#...';
   // or (depending on use)
   window.location.href = '#...';
   ```
3. Listen for changes with

   ```
   $(window).bind('hashchange',function()
   {
       ...
   });
   ```

Hope this helps.

**Edit:** includes a basic working example:

1. Create a file `index.html`
2. Inside `head` of `index.html`:

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
   // load data from hash value (map it to url)
   function load_hash() {
       var hash = window.location.hash;
       var content = $('#content');
       if (hash == '#about') {
           content.load('about.html');
       }
       else if (hash == '#contact') {
           content.load('contact.html');
       }
   }

   // load data based on hash and listen to changes
   $(document).ready(function() {
       load_hash();
       $(window).bind('hashchange', function() {
           load_hash();
       });
   });
   </script>
   ```
3. Inside `body` of `index.html`:

   ```
   <a href="#about">About</a>
   <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
   <div id="content"></div>
   ```
4. Create the files `about.html` and `contact.html` in the same directory; put any text in these but make sure you can distinguish between the two (For example, I put `<h1>About</h1>` and `<h1>Contact</h1>` appropriately)